# Request multiple parameters with one search term

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm new using JSON and I've created an API using Amazon's AWS service to work as a database for my dictionary website.

On the site there is a search bar which when receiving an input goes through my JavaScript to my JSON database to look for the search parameter given. For example "hello" as shown in the code below.

However my problem is that the only thing fetched to my JavaScript is the "hello" and none of the other things.

I know I'm new, but I would appreciate some tips on how i can make it possible using a search parameter get everything shown below.

```
[
  {
    "word": "hello",
    "phonetic": "həˈləʊ",
    "phonetics": [
      {
        "text": "həˈləʊ",
        "audio": "//ssl.gstatic.com/dictionary/static/sounds/20200429/hello--_gb_1.mp3"
      },
      {
        "text": "hɛˈləʊ"
      }
    ],
    "origin": "early 19th century: variant of earlier hollo ; related to holla.",
    "meanings": [
      {
        "partOfSpeech": "exclamation",
        "definitions": [
          {
            "definition": "used as a greeting or to begin a phone conversation.",
            "example": "hello there, Katie!"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: I suspect you just want to apply a filter, perhaps using `includes()`. But you've not really provided enough info here. Where's your sample code? What variable is this "dictionary" object assigned to? Are you doing the search within AWS code, and if so, what language does the AWS function use? Keep in mind that this the first we're seeing your problem, so we don't have the context you do.

Comment: Is the structure above showing what you currently get from the api, or what you’d like to get?  We’ll need to see some of your code please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter to search through the array for a string matching the word.

```js
let data = [
  {
    "word": "hello",
    "phonetic": "həˈləʊ",
    "phonetics": [
      {
        "text": "həˈləʊ",
        "audio": "//ssl.gstatic.com/dictionary/static/sounds/20200429/hello--_gb_1.mp3"
      },
      {
        "text": "hɛˈləʊ"
      }
    ],
    "origin": "early 19th century: variant of earlier hollo ; related to holla.",
    "meanings": [
      {
        "partOfSpeech": "exclamation",
        "definitions": [
          {
            "definition": "used as a greeting or to begin a phone conversation.",
            "example": "hello there, Katie!"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
    {
    "word": "TEST",
    "phonetic": "həˈləʊ",
    "phonetics": [
      {
        "text": "həˈləʊ",
        "audio": "//ssl.gstatic.com/dictionary/static/sounds/20200429/hello--_gb_1.mp3"
      },
      {
        "text": "hɛˈləʊ"
      }
    ],
    "origin": "early 19th century: variant of earlier hollo ; related to holla.",
    "meanings": [
      {
        "partOfSpeech": "exclamation",
        "definitions": [
          {
            "definition": "used as a greeting or to begin a phone conversation.",
            "example": "hello there, Katie!"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
let search = "HELLO";
let found = data.filter((row) => {
    return (row.word.toLowerCase() == search.toLowerCase())  
});

console.log(found)
```